# Google maps API v3 DrawingManager predefined polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build route on google maps api v3 with polygons. I have already predefined route which I need to allow to edit. Problem is my predefined polylines are not showing up on map. What am I missing here?

```
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.ROADMAP,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
      ]
    },
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: '#ff0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      zIndex: 1,
      editable: true,
      path: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
      ],
      visible: true
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add polylines in the polylineOptions, the "path" is ignored.  See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManagerOptions)

> polylineOptions | PolylineOptions | Options to apply to any new polylines created with this 
>   DrawingManager. **The path property is ignored**, and the map property of a new polyline is 
>   always set to the DrawingManager's map.

[Example of DrawingManager with pre-loaded Polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)